# what happens when we do sudo apt-get upgrade python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I did:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade python3
```

and then:

```
python3 --version
```

but still shows: Python 3.5.2, where I was expecting Python 3.7.3 which is the latest version so far.

Why and what happened here?

Can someone please explain in detail about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Linux distros still link `/usr/bin/python` to `python2` rather than `python3`. If you just want to casually run Python 3, type `python3` on the command-line. Use `pip3` to install packages for that interpreter when you would normally use `pip`.

What I would **not** recommend doing is using your sudo powers to update the `python` symlink. There are too many system scripts that rely on `/usr/bin/python` being `python2` for this to be a good idea.

If you want finer-grained control over Python interpreters, use a platform manager like Anaconda or Miniconda. Unlike normal Ubuntu packages, you can install it for the local user, so it won't require root access to maintain. You can also point your `PATH` variable to include the Anaconda version of `python` first, without affecting the rest of the system at all. Here is an example of installation instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-anaconda-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart.

For even more manual control, use virtualenvs.

Going the other way, the simplest solution might be to just define an alias for `python` in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: but doing 'sudo apt-get upgrade python3' won't remove anything but only adds an independent new version right?

Comment: It updates an existing independent version, but yes, it won't break any existing packages.

Answer (score 4):

Updating Python 3 using `sudo apt-get upgrade python3` doesn't change the symlink automatically. In other words, if you try:

```sh
which python3
```

The response will be:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

And if you try:

```sh
ls -l /usr/bin/python3
```

The response will be:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
```

This indicates that your `python3` command still points to your `python3.5` installation. But, why? In theory if you upgrade, the minor version should go up, right?

Well, it's not the case for Python in apt, apparently. When you upgrade `python3.5`, you're upgrading the minor-minor version inside 3.5, but not moving out from 3.5. In other words, you'll have the most updated 3.5 version, but not the most updated 3 version.

To install, let's say, Python 3.10, you'll need to install a new version, mentioning also the minor version. Turns out that you'll also need to import an apt-specific repository through its [PPA key](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas). [This repository is called "deadsnakes"](https://github.com/deadsnakes).

## Step-by-step about how to do it

First, update and upgrade everything, install `software-properties-common` package (to deal with PPA keys), import deadsnakes PPA repository and update the apt index again:

```sh
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Second, install your chosen Python version, specifying explicitly the minor version:

```sh
sudo apt install python3.10 python3.10-venv python3.10-dev
```

This doesn't update the symlink automatically. You'll need to update the symbolic links, using one of the two methods below. The first one is a little bit better, using [`update-alternatives`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives). I'll describe both just for educational purposes.

### Method one: `update-alternatives`

Run the following commands:

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.5 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 2
```

This registers your Python versions in `update-alternatives`. To change the Python version, use:

```sh
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

A menu with choices will be shown. You can select the version you want to use.

### Method two: Manual symbolic link update

If you opted by not using `update-alternatives`, you'll need to also execute:

```sh
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.10 /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.10-config /usr/bin/python3-config
```

This should be enough. If you run your `python3` again, you should have it updated:

```
$ python3
Python 3.10.0a6 (default, Mar  2 2021, 02:01:08) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 is a different package than Python 2. So, python 2 can't be upgraded into python3.

`sudo apt-get upgrade python3` it only upgrade python3 package. By default `python` command takes `python2` interpreter. So either make `alias python=python3` in `~/.bashrc` file to run python3 using python command.

Or, run it using:

```
python3
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you should be using is `python3` instead of `python`.

By default Ubuntu takes `Python2` for `python` command

Answer (score 0):

This show the default version of python in OS, whereas you upgraded python3.

```
python --version
```

To use upgraded version of python you should type in python in terminal and hit tab to check available versions

you will get somewhat like this

```
python
python              python2.7           python2-config      python2-pbr            python3.6           python3.6m          python3-config      python3m            python-config       
python2             python2.7-config    python2-jsonschema  python3             python3.6-config    python3.6m-config   python3-jsonschema  python3m-config
```

Then use the desired verion of python.